# Unable to set custom (correct) resolution on X11 and Wayland when using Arc 380 (i915)

Tags: x11, wayland, resolution, intel-graphics, i915

I have a monitor with a native resolution that is as comfortable as unusual (1920x860), I am on Artix (6.8.2-artix1-1), and I am using Kde Plasma 6 (plasmashell 6.0.2).

I have an iGPU (Intel Iris Pro II) and a GPU (Intel Arc 380).

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 6200 (rev 0a)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation DG2 [Arc A380] (rev 05)
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.3-arch1.2
```

If I connect the monitor to the iGPU, the monitor works fine. If I connect it to the GPU I have only one resolution available:1280x720. This resolution does not respect the screen ratio and therefore everything is stretched and smeared.

I checked the edid file on linux via get-edid | parse-edid, from Linux I get little information. I was thus able to delve into the edid file on Windows 10 Using EnTech Monitor Asset Manager.

I got a complete readout of the edid file, and this is where the interesting news popped up: the edid.bin file of my monitor reads:

```
Native/preferred timing... 1920x860p at 60Hz 
    Modeline............... "1920x860" 110,680 1920 1968 2000 2106 860 863 868 876 +hsync +vsync

Standard timings supported
    1280 x 720p at 60Hz - VESA STD
```

So I tried using the edid.bin file and:

- I put the edid file in /usr/lib/firmware/edid/.
- I set `MODULES=(i915)` and `FILES="/usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin"` in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf. Then ran `# mkinitcpio -P`
- I put the KMS `drm.edid_firmware=HDMI-1:edid/edid.bin drm.edid_firmware=HDMI-A-1:edid/edid.bin` in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT of /etc/default/grub. Then clearly run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (I set the custom edid two times since HDMI-1 is the way X11 identifies my monitor and HDMI-A-1 since it is the way Wayland identifies it).

Now if I check with dmesg there is no errors and the edid file is loaded correctly without any problems, as is the i915 module.

The Xorg log is also completely clean, there are no problems. The i915 driver is loaded correctly and the only missing feature (due to my motherboard) is the resizeable BAR, which is not important to solve this problem.

Despite this, on both Wayland and X11 the only resolution that can be set is 1280x720 (always stretched). Using X11 and xrandr I can add the modeline 1920x1080 and use it (maybe because it is Standard) but still everything is stretched since it doesn't respect the screen ratio.

So I tried configuring inside /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "IntelGraphics"
    Driver "modesetting"
#    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "DRI" "iris"
#   Option "DRI" "2"
    Option "CustomEDID" "HDMI-1:/usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin"
    Option "CustomEDID" "HDMI-A-1:/usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin"
    Option "IgnoreEDID" "false"
    Option "UseEDID" "true"
EndSection
```

But despite all this, on both X11 and Wayland the only resolution that can be set is 1280x720.

Trying this way I get some warnings in the Xorg log, since Driver "modesetting" has no edid options:

```
[     5.973] (WW) modeset(0): Option "DRI" is not used
[     5.973] (WW) modeset(0): Option "CustomEDID" is not used
[     5.973] (WW) modeset(0): Option "IgnoreEDID" is not used
[     5.973] (WW) modeset(0): Option "UseEDID" is not used
[     5.973] (WW) modeset(0): Option "DisplaySize" is not used
[     5.993] (WW) modeset(G0): Option "DisplaySize" is not used
```

I also tried to use xf86-video-intel, so setting Driver "intel" (that is way I left the # comments in the 20-intel.conf), but this way doesn't work since xf86-video-intel doesn't work with this GPU.

I tried to user xrandr on X11 to therefore add by hand the modeline specified in the edid file ("1920x860" 110,680 1920 1968 2000 2106 860 863 868 876 +hsync +vsync). Doesn't work.

If I use the Arc 830 it seems that I can only set the Vesa Standard resolution (1280x720) and not the preferred one indicated in the edid file (1920x860). This is so annoying.

I hope someone can help me or can give me further guidance and that this information can be a guide for those in the same situation as me. I would like to do a bug report in regard to this issue, but doesn't know where/who.

Summary:

1. my display monitor has a nonstandard resolution;
2. Intel Iris Pro II detects it correctly, Intel Arc 380 does not (it only makes me set 1 incorrect Standard resolution for the screen);
3. if I load the edid file via Kernel Mode Settings at startup and everything loads correctly with lots of happy i915, however, the situation with the Arc 380 does not change;
4. this happens on both Wayland and X11;
5. if on X11 I add the resolution by hand using `xrandr` with the modesetting provided in the edid file (or even calculated via `cvt`) the situation does not change: on Intel Arc 380 and my monitor I can only get 1 Standard resolution;
6. frustration.

Hope someone can help me out with this issue.

ps: if some info or reports are needed please let me know.